# Show that $\mathbb E(X_n) \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} \mathbb E(X)$ using the following decomposition.

Tags: probability-theory, uniform-integrability

> Suppose that each $X_n$ and $X$ are non-negative random variables and $X_n \stackrel d \to X.$ Assume that $\{X_n \}_{n \geq 1}$ is uniformly integrable. Prove the following decomposition $$\mathbb E(X_n) = \int_{0}^{M} \mathbb P (M \geq X_n \gt t)\ dt + \int_{X_n \gt M} X_n\ d \mathbb P.$$ Hence, show that $\mathbb E(X_n)$ converges to $\mathbb E(X).$ Argue that the same is true even if we did not assume non-negativity.

I am able to show that decomposition. I also showed that if $\{X_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ is a sequence of random variables (not necessarily non-negative) and $X_n \stackrel d \to X$ then $X_n^+ \stackrel d \to X^+$ and $X_n^- \stackrel d \to X^-.$ I also showed that if $\{X_n \}_{n \geq 1}$ is uniformly integrable then so are $\{X_n^+ \}_{n \geq 1}$ and $\{X_n^- \}_{n \geq 1}.$ So if we can able to show that $\mathbb E(X_n) \to \mathbb E(X)$ for non-negative sequence of random variables $\{X_n \}_{n \geq 1}$ satisfying uniform integrability I can able to extend the same idea for any sequence of random variables satisfying uniform integrability.

Could anyone kindly give some idea on how to use the decomposition to conclude that $\mathbb E(X_n) \xrightarrow {n \to \infty} \mathbb E(X)\ $? Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that one of the definitions of uniform integrability (people use a lot of different ones, so if you have one in mind you have to specify) is that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is some $M$ such that $$\mathbb E[|X_n| \cdot 1_{|X_n| > M}] = \int_{|X_n| > M} |X_n| d\mathbb P < \epsilon.$$

As you said, we may take $X_n$ nonnegative without loss of generality, so that we can drop the absolute values above. We first show that $\mathbb E[X] < \infty$, as by Fatou
$$\mathbb E[X] = \int_0^\infty \lim_n \mathbb P(X_n > t)dt \leq \liminf_n \int_0^\infty \mathbb P(X_n > t)dt = \liminf_n \mathbb E[X_n] < \infty.$$

Now, by the decomposition in the problem,
$$
\mathbb E[X] - \mathbb E[X_n] = \int_0^M (\mathbb P(t < X \leq M) - \mathbb P(t < X_n \leq M))dt + \int_{X>M} X d\mathbb P - \int_{X_n>M} X_n d\mathbb P.
$$
For any $\epsilon > 0$, by uniform integrability and the fact that $\mathbb E[X] < \infty$, we can choose $M$ such that both of the latter integrals are bounded by $\epsilon$. Then the above reduces to
$$
\mathbb E[X] - \mathbb E[X_n] \leq \int_0^M (\mathbb P(t < X \leq M) - \mathbb P(t < X_n \leq M))dt + 2\epsilon.
$$
Now, by convergence in distribution, $$\mathbb P(t < X \leq M) - \mathbb P(t < X_n \leq M) \to 0$$ and
we can conclude by dominated convergence that for sufficiently large $n$, $$\int_0^M (\mathbb P(t < X \leq M) - \mathbb P(t < X_n \leq M))dt < \epsilon.$$

So we have shown that for any $\epsilon > 0$, for sufficiently large $n$, $$\mathbb E[X] - \mathbb E[X_n] < 3\epsilon$$
and so we may conclude.

Comment: Here the only part where I have a little confusion is where you use distributional convergence. Note that if $t \notin C (F_X)$ we cannot say $$\mathbb P (M \geq X_n \gt t) \xrightarrow {n \to \infty} \mathbb P (M \geq X \gt t)$$ according to the definition of distributional convergence. We can break the difference into $$(F_{X_n} (M) - F_{X} (M)) + (F_{X_n} (t) - F_{X} (t)).$$ I have a control over the first part for proper choice of $M.$ The second part is something where we do not have control over.

Comment: Sure. Note that the discontinuity points of $F_X$ are of measure zero (they're countable) so the limit is 0 up to a measure zero set, where the difference is what you've written. Since we only really care about the integral of that difference, being nonzero (and finite) on a null set is fine.

Comment: Note that this concern also shows up in the second display equation, where we wrote $\int P(X > t)dt = \int \lim P(X_n > t)dt$.

Comment: The concern that I mentioned can be easily tackled using the fact that $F_X,$ being the cdf of $X,$ has countably many discontinuities and hence the set of discontinuities of $F_X$ has Lebesgue measure zero. Note that DCT can also be applied to the situation where the notion of everywhere convergence is replaced by convergence almost surely.

Comment: Yes? Sorry if I am misunderstanding something; that seems to be what I wrote as well.

Comment: $:$ Sorry for misunderstanding; that supposed to be what you wrote as well? What I said that the DCT you applied is justified because of the existence of the version of DCT for almost sure convergence. Same is true when you applied Fatou's lemma.